# JQuery .post method problem with comma in php

Tags: php, jquery

This Works fine and count returns 2:

```
$request_ids="166409183417843,1913616994605";
$sent   = explode(',',$request_ids);
$count = count($sent);
```

But when using Jquery to post to another page sent var returns only the last id and count returns 1.

Page of origion:

```
$(function(){
      $.post("process_ids.php", { request_ids: response.request_ids } );})
```

process_ids.php file:

```
$sent   = explode(',', $_POST['request_ids']); 
$count = count($sent);
```

I also checked with alert() the value of response.request_ids value and it's the same.
Something is totally screwed here, what's wrong?

Comment: the same 166409183417843,1913616994605 . I also checked it with alert

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['request_ids'])`?

Comment: What does `count($sent)` give you? Does that line execute?

Comment: count($sent) gives me the number of object i would then need to loop through

Comment: You should check exactly what data is sent/received with Fiddler - maybe you are using a different data type or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own question but it's better than no answer.
The problem was like some mentioned above - the data type of the variable.

I simply cast the string to it before sending:

```
$(function(){
      $.post("process_ids.php", { request_ids: String(response.request_ids) } ); 
      return false;
});
```